# How to force Samba to use SMB 3.0?

Tags: security, configuration, samba, smb

With SMB 1.0/CIFS being [removed from Windows 10](https://thehackernews.com/2017/06/windows-10-redstone3-smb.html) in Redstone 3 update due to vulnerability, this will conk out a lot of systems relying on older network hard drive enclosures.

I have a Linux-based device (Raspberry Pi) that I could connect up to the drive with USB, but I'm not sure on this point:

Is there a way to restrict Samba on the Pi to using only SMB 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`server min protocol`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html#SERVERMINPROTOCOL) option in `smb.conf`:

> This setting controls the minimum protocol version that the server will allow the client to use.

Possible values are listed in documentation for [`server max protocol`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html#SERVERMAXPROTOCOL) option.

The documentation matching the samba version installed on your system should be available with [`man smb.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/smb.conf.5.html).

Comment: In the `[global]` section, this is [explained](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html#idp52819024) in the documentation as well.

Comment: Yep, I've added it to `[global]`, but it's not accepting server min protocol at all, min protocol of SMB3 or SMB3_00 are both not accepted either.


[2017/10/16 14:03:57,  0] smbd/server.c:1053(main) smbd version 3.6.6 started.


Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
[2017/10/16 14:03:57,  0] param/loadparm.c:7913(lp_set_enum_parm)
  WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'SMB3' for parameter 'min protocol'


[2017/10/16 14:01:59.411842,  0] param/loadparm.c:7913(lp_set_enum_parm)
  WARNING: Ignoring invalid value 'SMB3_00' for parameter 'min protocol'

Comment: You should refer to the documentation *matching* the version of samba you have. The old version (3.6.6) of samba on your system likely doesn't  have support for SMB3, check the documentation on *your system*. (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ships with 3.6.3, which is quite close if you need online documentation: [`man smb.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/smb.conf.5.html))

Comment: I've done `apt-get update`/`upgrade`. According to [Samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/SMB3_kernel_status#Introduction), the recommended Linux kernel SMB3 support is kernel version 3.18 or later (or equivalent, ie cifs module version 2.04 or later). I've checked cifs via modinfo cifs, I have 2.06. I've checked kernel version via `uname -a`, I have 4.1.19, and `cat /etc/debian_version` is 7.11. The Pi should support a better samba, any ideas why not?

Comment: cifs module is for kernel client, not server which is userspace. For SMB3 you need [Samba 4.0.0](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba3/SMB2#Introduction) or later.

Comment: I guess Pi B is no good. Thanks for your help.